# Duda sobre clases y objetos

Tags: python, poo

tengo una duda sobre el método de atacar, el cuál tendría que restarle la vida del personaje que es pasado como parámetro, por ejemplo si hago p1.atacar(p2) este tendría que restarle la medida del daño y esa sería la nueva vida.
mi código es este:

```
class personaje:
    def __init__(self,nombre,vida,poder,daño):
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.vida=vida
        self.poder=poder
        self.daño=daño

    def getvida(self):
        return self.vida

    def getdaño(self):
        return self.daño

    def atacar(self,otro):
        nuevavida=otro.getvida()-otro.getdaño()
        return nuevavida


    def tienevida(self):
        if self.getvida>0:
            return True


    def __str__(self):
        return (f"nombre : '{self.nombre}' vida : {self.vida}: poder : {self.poder} daño : {self.daño} ")




p1=personaje("Naomi",80,"tonta",90)
p2=personaje("Nacho",80,"Inteligencia",90)
p1.atacar(p2)
p2.atacar(p1)
print(p2)
print(p1)
```

Comment: No estas guardando el resultado del método atacar en la vida actual del personaje atacado. Si no lo haces ese valor se pierde. Después de la linea `nuevavida=otro.getvida()-otro.getdaño()` añade esta nueva `otro.vida=nuevavida` y listo

Answer (score 0):

yo haría algo parecido a esto

```
def atacar(self,otro):
        otro.setvida(otro.getvida()-self.getdaño())
        if (otro.tienevida):return otro
        else:print(otro," Estoy muerto que me importa si falla el código!!!!")

p1.atacar(p2).atacar(p1)
```

y cada uno se quitaría vida al otro, faltaría implementar set vida

Answer (score 0):

tienes dos opciones
la mas complicada y larga.
1.Cojer la variable a la cual hiciste `return` y restarselo al argumento `p2.vida`.

```
p1=personaje("Naomi",80,"tonta",90)
p2=personaje("Nacho",80,"Inteligencia",90)
ataque=p1.atacar(p2)
p2.vida-=ataque
print(p2)
```

y listo.
Oh

2.la mas corta en la parte donde dices:

```
def atacar(self,otro):
        nuevavida=otro.getvida()-otro.getdaño()
        otro.vida=nuevavida
```

ya si quieres saber cuanta vida tiene el P2 puedes usar la linea `return nuevavida`